# Swift refresh of lineChartView View

Tags: swift

Could somebody gives me an advice?
I have swift 3.0 app with Split view and lineChartView.
When I load detailView my lineChart is correct. See pic 1.
[original correct View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loIgC.png)

When I move detail's screen to full screen then my lineChartView is moved and not refreshed. But I do this. My code is below.

[Not correct View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dAk8.png)

When I just tap graph then my lineChartView is refreshed and it is correct again.

I catched moving of screen and try reload lineChartView but without result.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if loadedGraph  {
        showGraph(reload: false) //here false means reload from internet data source.
    }
    if UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation) {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("NOT Landscape")
    }
}
func showGraph(reload : Bool) {
    lineChartView.layer.frame.size.width = graphView.layer.frame.width
    var max = maxElement(graph: DataArrayNew)
    if !(max > 0) {
        max = 1
    }
    graphView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    graphView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:85/255.0, green:85/255.0, blue:85/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    if reload {
        _ = NarodMon.sharedInstance.getHistoricalData(interval: horizontalMarker, device:  sensorID)
    }
    DataArrayNew = (NarodMon.sharedInstance.getDataArray() as NSArray) as! [Double]
    TimeArrayNew = (NarodMon.sharedInstance.getTimeArray() as NSArray) as! [String]
    DataArray = (NarodMon.sharedInstance.getDataArrayOrig() as NSArray) as! [Double]
    lineChartView.maximumValue = CGFloat(max)
    lineChartView.reloadData()
}
```

Any actions like setNeedsDisplay() or reloadInputViews() don't help.

But if I tap graph then graph got normal view.

Any ideas how to fix this I'll very appreciate.

Rg, Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

You can load your graph in

```
    func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Hope this help.